# AngularJS: I have the same function in more than one controller. Keeping DRY in mind, what's the best solution?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.getNote = function (note) {
        return 'http://mydummyaudiofile.com/'+note+'.mp3';
    };
    $scope.notes = function(note){
            var id = "audio-"+note;
            var audio = document.getElementById("audio-"+note);
               audio.load();
               audio.play();
    };
}]);
```

The code as it is written is functioning. If you are curious, it is essentially a keyboard that loops through an array of audio files using ng-repeat, and has them line up with the correct keys. Again, this works already, but I am making several different controllers with different arrays of audio files (several types of keyboards), and I don't want to copy/paste the code several times. Is there a solution that allows me to "scope" the function so that I can still use ng-repeat? I have tried using a factory, but it failed. So far the solution seems to be using a custom directive, but before I spend any more time messing with it I wanted to make sure there wasn't an alternative.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you want a custom directive. Have you tried that route?

Comment: That's where I was heading. I should've (and will) put that in my question.

Comment: I agree with @Randyaa, you can build a directive that receives an array of audio files and performs the common operations.